# Bootstrap - Collapsed menu items appearing horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason no matter what I do my navbar displays menu items horizontally on collapse with my logo in the middle of them! When I used the visible-xs etc it aligns it to the left for some reason when it is visible!

I have tried methods found on other similar overflow questions such as displaying the list items inline-block (despite not wanting to use inline-styles!)

But nothing is working for me!

I know the problem is because I have my logo in the center of my menu items on desktop view, so it isn't a standard menu but there must be a way around this to make my menu items display vertically without the logo in the middle? I am new-ish to this so perhaps I am just being stupid and missing something?

I am using jquery mobile if it makes any difference (could it be this breaking the menu and preventing it from being closed?)

here is what I have and have tried:

HTML for navbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, no-index">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head; any other head content must come after these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="favv.ico">


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>



  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="../node_modules/jquery-mobile/mobilestyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/Silver-Lining/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet">



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">


  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


  <![endif]>






  <!--============ Navigation ===============-->



  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top text-center">


    <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="top-social">
            <a href="tel:+1-303-499-7111"> <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true">   
     </i> 0787000000
            </a>

            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

          </div>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="about-us.php" data-ajax="false">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php" data-ajax="false">OUR CARS</a></li>
            <li><a href="Prices.php" data-ajax="false">PRICES</a></li>
            <a class="hidden-sm-down" href="index.php" data-ajax="false"><img src="../assets/images/logo" width="250" alt="Logo"></a>
            <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false">PACKAGES</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php" data-ajax="false">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php" data-ajax="false">CONTACT</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

CSS example to make menu items appear vertically on Collapse:

```
 @media (max-width: 932px) {
   #navbar-primary .navbar-nav li a {
     float: none;
     position: inherit;
     display: inline-block !important;
     vertical-align: top;
     max-height: 300px;
   }
 }
```

Css for navbar

```
// Remove excess borders
.navbar-default {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-color: transparent;
  white-space: normal;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I have been very confused and stuck on this for several days at least and really want to keep the same navbar without having to make it all over again

Comment: The causes for this could be multiple and we might not be able to tell you exactly what is happening as you have some custom `css` files imported. If you somehow replicate this issue in `snippet` or `fiddle` we could hopefully help you in some way.. :)

Comment: I used this tutorial so it is pretty much like this but with some added social icons etc https://codepen.io/davidcochran/pen/Fkwys I cannot seem to get it to work properly on js fiddle

Comment: Noticed on collapse the menu items are horizontal like mine - Any help or suggestions much appreciated!! If you can make a js fiddle of this with what I need to add to get it working properly I am sure I can implement it! Thanks and sorry for not posting a js fiddle!

Comment: Paste your custom `js`, `css` and `html` code in fiddle. Everything. and whatever external files like the one loading from `cdn` paste it as external resource in fiddle.. We have to somehow replicate it..

Comment: I have a lot of code!! Many scripts to files etc.. I think this is why it wont work.

Comment: But that link is litterally my menu, I just customised it for my website. If you see the link to the code I used you will see it has the same issue there, I just need to figure out why that menu displays items horizonally on collapse and I can apply it to mine as it is pretty much identical.. plus a lot less code for you to look at!

Comment: www.codepen.io/davidcochran/pen/Fkwys

Comment: I just know it is something to do with the logo being centred in between the navbar menu items.. as I have made many a navbar and never had this issue, but I specifically wanted the logo centred inside it

Answer (score 0):

After much playing with the code I found that

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li {
display: block;
}
}
```

gave me the result I wanted (vertically stacked menu items on collapse!)